# How do we can pass string Date in list and can retrieve from database in to a list

Tags: android, string, sqlite, date

This is my code and I want to save date into my database and want to get saved into list.
How do we can store date in database? how can we save date like `int` or `String`?
 It is showing curly red line below "datePickerBtn1",  "datePickerBtn2", "datePickerBtn3". I have used button to show date dialogs but I want to store date as text in list. 
i am trying to make Notepad or task reminder.

```
case R.id.savebutton:
    String subject = editsubject.getText().toString();
    String description =editdescription.getText().toString();
    int created = datepickerbtn1.getText().toString();        //save into database and get list
    int due = datepickerbtn2.getText().toString();
    int completed = datepickerbtn3.getText().toString();**

    if(!subject.equals("") || !description.equals("")) {
        Database_List db = new Database_List(this);
        db.addList(subject, description, created, due, completed );
    }

break;
```

Comment: In database you can save the date with the help of DATE FIELD and if you want to use it in your Android code then you can easily convert it to string.

Comment: And how to save date in database int created = datepickerbtn1.getText().toString();

Comment: Shweta, its not essential to save the dates in DATE FIELD only, You can save dates in String form as you are already getting it in String Formate...

Comment: See Changdeo answer the same what I said....so problem solved I think:)

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering how could you compile your code with these lines in code

```
int created = datepickerbtn1.getText().toString();        //save into database and get list
    int due = datepickerbtn2.getText().toString();
```

Please change this to

```
String created = datepickerbtn1.getText().toString();        //save into database and get list
    String due = datepickerbtn2.getText().toString();
```

And you can store date as string or as DATE field. For simplicity store is as String.